# Enabling new light turns off latest enabled light

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I want to be able to enable multiple lights at anytime.

If I enable multiple lights simultaneously then no problem, but after that when I try to enable a new light the latest light that was enabled from the previous lights group is turned off.

How can I solve this, I already increased Pixel light count to 1000 and set lightRenderMode to force pixel

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: The code is too big and complicated to post, but I enable a group of lights by a Mylightgroup.enabled = true; inside a for loop then when I enable a new light or a new group of lights the latest light that was enabled by the first for loop is turned off.
Thank you for your help

Comment: try taking setting the render mode for all your lights  to important

Comment: I tried to do this but renderMode offers only 3 possibilities (auto, Force pixel and force vertex)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of unity? Take a look here, the 3 possibilities for Render Mode are Auto, Important and Not Important. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Light.html

Comment: In the editor yes, but in the code LightRenderMode has 3 options: auto, Force pixel and force vertex please correct me if I am confusing some thing (I am using Unity 5.2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100191/discussion-between-gabriel-ilharco-and-tarik-mokafih).

Comment: Check if you have a global reference to a light component. That reference might be set to false while creating new ones. Since it is global, it keeps the last created as reference.

Comment: Hi @fafase what do you mean by a global reference ? thank you

Comment: global as class member instead of local member to the method.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is in your hierarchy

lets say you have

- MainLight

  - light 1
  - light 2

    - light 5
  - light 3
  - light 4

some of the stuff you will do to light 2 will affect light 5

Sometime, when the error seems impossible it mean there is a good chance it is a small error of attention that we dont even bother to check.

this happen often to me, the more complex the code the more stupid the error is.

Comment: I hoped it was the case, but not. all my lights are undependent from each other